# Extract facebook url from embed code

Tags: regex, facebook, amp-html

I need regex to match the code below and extract facebook url.
i.e - https://www.facebook.com/somevide/videos/778978567/

```html
    <div id="fb-root"></div> <script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/somevide/videos/778978567/" data-width="640" data-show-text="false"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex all code and video url

```
(<div id="fb-root[\s\S.]*?data-href="([^"]+).*fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><\/div><\/div>)
```

regex video url

```
data-href="([^"]+)
```

using javascript dom

```
var videoUrl = document.getElementsByClassName('fb-video')[0].getAttribute('data-href');
console.log(videoUrl);
```